# Reusing a footer among multiple HTML pages

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working on a web template which provides 5 HTML pages. I was surprised that inside each page there is the same footer section, as follow:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footerrow1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 maxheight1 footercol1">
                    <a class="smallogo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logosmall.png" alt=""></a>
                    <ul class="social_icons clearfix">
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="img/follow_icon1.png" alt=""></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="img/follow_icon2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="img/follow_icon3.png" alt=""></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="img/follow_icon4.png" alt=""></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="img/follow_icon5.png" alt=""></a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 maxheight1 footercol1">
                    <h5>our Location</h5>
                    <div class="smalladdress">
                        <p class="mainaddress">9870 St Vincent Place,<br>Glasgow, DC 45 Fr 45.</p>
                        <p>Freephone:<span>+1 800 559 6580</span></p>
                        <p>Telephone:<span>+1 800 603 6035</span></p>
                        <p>FAX:<span class="marginfax">+1 800 889 9898</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 maxheight1 footercol1">
                    <h5>Overview</h5>
                    <ul class="list5">
                        <li><a href="#">what we do</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sales for services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 maxheight1 footercol1">
                    <h5 class="mbotform1">newsletter</h5>
                    <form id="form1">
                      <div class="success">Your subscribe request<br> has been sent!</div>
                        <fieldset>
                        <label class="email">
                            <input type="email" value="Enter Your Email">
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span></label>
                        <br class="clear">
                        <div class="btns"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn4" data-type="submit">Submit</a></div>
                      </fieldset>
                      </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerrow2">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="footerpriv" style="text-align:center">&copy; <span id="copyright-year"></span> <img src="img/linefooter.png" alt=""> <a class="privacylink" href="index-5.html">Privacy Policy</a></p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</footer>
```

If I need to modify it, I need to modify each of the 5 HTML pages. I am an ASP.net MVC web developer where i can easily handle this by defining a layout view which each contain all the shared sections.

So my question is how I can manage this inside my web template's HTML pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no* (with an asterik).

*There is [some support in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) for include-able HTML but it is [very limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=HTML%20Imports).

So little support, in fact, that Firefox ..."has no plans to support HTML imports"...

You may have luck using the [Web Components Library](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/) to enable cross-browser support, but that may be more trouble than it is worth for a 5 page template.